# Catching Errors From Cloudinary In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloudinary

I am trying to delete images in Cloudinary from my Rails application using the following code

```
def destroy
    media = Media.find(params[:id])

    Cloudinary::Uploader.destroy(media.image_id)
    media.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index' }
        format.xml { head :ok }
    end
end
```

Aside from the Uploader.destroy method not actually deleting the image file from my media library^, what I need is to get any return code or error information from the operation. If the delete fails for any reason, I don't want to continue on and delete the media record from the database.

I've been looking through the Cloudinary gem and Googling, but haven't seen anything obvious. Can anyone show me what to do here?

^ *I think it's not deleting because I am giving it the wrong image_id. Still working on that.*

Comment: [Sample error here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images) and details on [Rails API here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_upload).

Comment: Where do I get the error response from? Is there a method I need to call, or is it in a variable?

Comment: Did you try `result = Cloudinary::Uploader.destroy(media.image_id)` and logging the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary returns the result of the deletion.
You can use something like:

```
result = Cloudinary::Uploader.destroy(media.image_id)
```

and then check whether `result["result"]` is `"ok"` or `"not found"`